# How to tell cell phone to install midlet in applications folder?

Tags: manifest, java-me, nokia, midlet, jad

I'd like to suggest where the phone should install the j2me app. For instance, on Nokia phones, it always install them in games folder. Is there a way to suggest a destination folder? Either in .jad file or in MANIFEST file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Nokias you can use `Nokia-MIDlet-Category` JAD parameter as described [here](http://www.forum.nokia.com/document/Java_ME_Developers_Library_v1/?content=GUID-C5D3E0F5-72B9-4EE7-8BA7-20DE4A538FB8.html).